# How can I create lambda PyObject from its Python code in a C string?

Tags: python, python-c-api

I have the following code in Python, which uses [`pyjexl` module](https://pypi.org/project/pyjexl):

```
import pyjexl

jexl = pyjexl.JEXL()
jexl.add_transform("lowercase", lambda x: str(x).lower())
```

I want to do the same using [Python C API](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/index.html). Something like this:

```c
Py_Initialize();
PyObject* pyjexlModule = PyImport_ImportModule("pyjexl");
PyObject* jexl = PyObject_CallMethod(pyjexlModule, "JEXL", NULL);

const char* myLambda = "lambda x: str(x).lower()";
PyObject* lambda = ... /* something using myLambda */
PyObject_CallMethod(jexl, "add_transform", "sO", "lowercase", lambda);
```

(Simplified version of the code, e.g., `NULL` checking and `Py_XDECREF()` have been omitted)

The problem I'm trying to solve is how to get a `PyObject` representing a lambda function which Python code is contained in the C-string `myLambda`.

How can I achieve this?

I have tried with the suggestion by @DavidW using this:

```c
PyObject* globals = PyDict_New();
PyObject* locals = PyDict_New();
PyObject* lambda = PyRun_String(myLambda, Py_eval_input, globals, locals);
```

But I think it's not working, as the resulting `lambda` variable (inspected using debugger) is of type `PyNone`:

[image: Debugger screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

[`PyRun_String`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/veryhigh.html#c.PyRun_String):

```
PyObject *lambda = PyRun_String(lambda, Py_eval_input, some_dict, some_dict);
```

where `some_dict` can be an empty dict. (I think on some older versions of Python you'd need to have `str` in the dict, so might need to use `PyEval_GetBuiltins` but this should be unnecessary now).

---

The exact function I tested with was

```
PyObject *makeLambda() {
        const char* myLambda = "lambda x: str(x).lower()";
        PyObject* globals = PyDict_New();
        PyObject* locals = PyDict_New();
        PyObject* lambda = PyRun_String(myLambda, Py_eval_input, globals, locals);
        return lambda;
    }
```

Note that I've omitted error handling for `PyDict_New()` - ideally there should be a NULL check after each of these.

In order to test it I built it into a Cython module - that's just because it provides an easy way to compile and call C functions so it's a quick way to test it:

```
cdef extern from *:
    """
    PyObject *makeLambda() {
        const char* myLambda = "lambda x: str(x).lower()";
        PyObject* globals = PyDict_New();
        PyObject* locals = PyDict_New();
        PyObject* lambda = PyRun_String(myLambda, Py_eval_input, globals, locals);
        return lambda;
    }
    """
    object makeLambda()

def callMakeLambda():
    return makeLambda()
```

The Cython module is compiled with `cythonize -if modulename.pyx`

You can then test it with

```
>>> import modulename
>>> modulename.callMakeLambda()
```

The second line returns `<function <lambda> at 0x7f72c0d8bc40>` (the exact address of the lambda will vary of course).

Comment: Thanks you for your feedback! I'm testing with your suggestions but it seems it not working... Please have a look to the EDIT section in the question post

Comment: Don't know. I just tested it now and it works for me. So I don't have any other suggestions

Comment: Can you provide the full code, please? In order to try to identify differences with my case... Thanks!

Comment: I've edited the answer to include the full code I used to test it